# Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: (XeroAPI)

Tags: php, guzzle, xero-api

Having an issue with the XERO API when trying for the first time. This is with a clean LAMP install with SSL certificate in place.

When I go to `authorization.php` it takes me to Xero to authenticate and then back to `callback.php` with the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /var/www/DOMAIN.CO.UK/public_html/xero/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:200 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/DOMAIN.CO.UK/public_html/xero/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(155): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection() #1 
/var/www/DOMAIN.CO.UK/public_html/xero/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(105): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError() #2 
/var/www/DOMAIN.CO.UK/public_html/xero/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish() #3 /var/www/DOMAIN.CO.UK/public_html/xero/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke() #4 
/var/www/DOMAIN.CO.UK/public_html/xero/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(51): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}() #5
/var/www/train in /var/www/DOMAIN.CO.UK/public_html/xero/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 200
```

I've no idea what this issue is and ive tried looking online everywhere with no joy.

My set up is:
Centos 8
PHP 7.4.6
Apache2

Comment: Is there any code involved you want to share? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Hi Nico, This is the API - https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2 

Ive basically used composer to set it up and created the files as requested with my app credentials. 

Im unsure how to debug this given its a packaged up API and not sure how it all works.

It must be something specific to my set up as its working for others.

Comment: Hello was this ever resolved. I am having a similar issue with OpenTok api